# Problem with logging in (Laravel Jetstream)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have the following problem: Always when I try to log in, on the first attempt the page is just reloading without performing any action like showing up a message for wrong credentials or something like this. On the second attempt everything works fine. Any ideas?

Laravel version: **8**

Comment: Maybe you should share your login method in the controller to help better. Also, check your session file in config/session.php and change 'same_site' value to 'null'.

Comment: I've changed the value to `null` but didn't helped at all. I have no idea how to get access to the login method in the controller which automatically means it is untouched by me so it shouldn't cause the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many, many researches for this kind of problem I think I found my specific solution. I've actually built a route long time ago for logging out which had the following code:

```
Auth::logout();
return redirect()->route('site.home');
```

I have no idea why I've created and used this route at all. According to jetstream's core code and my understandings that's not how you fully logout a user and destroy session. But here's how:

```
    /**
     * Destroy an authenticated session.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request): LogoutResponse
    {
        $this->guard->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return app(LogoutResponse::class);
    }
```

I've tested it right now and everything works fine.